# How do I use LibreOffice's 3d transitions in Impress?

Tags: 11.10, effects, presentation, libreoffice

How can I get the 3D transitions working on Impress? I got a presentation coming soon, and as a requirement of the course the professor want us to use transitions on our "Power Point" chapter, obviously I have been using LibreOffice in every exercise but the native transitions are kind of lame, so when I install the newer version of Ubuntu, always install the extra package to the transitions  - I had installed the 3D package:

`libreoffice-ogltrans 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2`

In previous versions of Ubuntu and worked perfectly, but for some reason is not working in this release.

I got LibreOffice 3.4.3, Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot (11.10) and my hardware is not relevant because I had it working before on previous releases.

I know is not critical, but for my class is a pretty important deal, and can be a perfect opportunity to show the class that the cool stuff are not only in Windows.

As a recomendation of one of Eliah Kagan, I'm putting the output of:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

```
*-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f6c00000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:efe8(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6b00000-f6bfffff
```

And I'm not using Unity - it don't there anyways -, I'm using instead Gnome Shell.

Comment: Your hardware is still potentially relevant, even though it was working on previous releases. Many users experience new graphics problems when they go from one release to another, and the solution is often specific to the hardware and drivers being used. What is the output of `sudo lshw -C video` (I recommend you add it to your question), and what session type are you in (e.g., Unity, Unity 2D, GNOME Classic)?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that ogltrans still does not yet work in Ubuntu 11.10 for LibreOffice 3.44 (OOO340m1 build 402) (refer to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/libreoffice-ogltrans/1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1). Hope this will be fixed soon so I can continue to "impress" people...

BTW, libreoffice-presenter-console also wasn't working until I updated it to 1.10 with the latest LibreOffice on 16-nov-2011.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing UBUNTU 10.04 LTS for this project then upgrade after it's completion if you desire. At least you know it will work and you could complete your project with confidence.